# overcrowded Earth in late 21st century, very large extended family in small apartment

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I don't recall too much of the story, except that the younger family members were resentful of the older ones for not dying already. The final line of the story was something like "It was the best that could be expected in the latter half of the 21st century."

I think that I read it in an anthology in the 1990s.

Comment: could it be a vonnegut story in which there was very cheap immortality via a drug. people end up living in jail cells to get some extra space?

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170976/looking-for-story-title-younger-gen-waters-down-age-slowing-drink-of-older-gen

Comment: It has appeared under different titles, "The Big Trip Up Yonder" and "Tomorrow and Tomorrow". You can read it here: https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v07_04_Galaxy_Jan_1954_AKv1.0#page/n101/mode/1up

Comment: The last line of Vonnegut's story: "Life was good. He could hardly wait to see what was going to happen next." Doesn't match the OP's recollection, so maybe this is the wrong story?

Comment: It is quite possible that I've conflated the story I'm seeking with the Vonengut story, in which case I may have the setting wrong. The story I'm seeking definitely ends with the final line I stated, or something quite similar. I realize that this may make it very difficult to identify. So it goes.

Comment: Could be Harrison’s Make Room! Make Room! (The Soylent Green book). Could also be the cut-down version of that, which was published as a novella (Roommates). It had old folks being “forcibly retired”, a small apartment where the main character’s roommate is eventually replaced by a large and obnoxious extended family. The main character is a detective.